# Check ID of a clicked item?

Tags: jquery

I have a delegate like:

```
$('#panel').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    // how do we get the ID of 'target'?
    var id = target.getId(?);
});
```

Yeah I'm just not sure how to get 'target's ID, because I want to check if it is a particular element to perform some action on later.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#panel').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
});
```

Comment: Is this common across all event models?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(event.target).attr('id');
```